# Using a guard clause with a Timex DateTime in Elixir

Tags: elixir

So I can use guard clauses to run different versions of a function based on the type of the argument:

```
iex(2)> defmodule Test do
...(2)> 
...(2)>   def double(x) when is_integer(x) do
...(2)>     x * 2
...(2)>   end
...(2)> 
...(2)>   def double(x) when is_binary(x) do
...(2)>     String.to_integer(x) * 2
...(2)>   end
...(2)> end

iex(3)> Test.double(2)
4
iex(4)> Test.double("2")
4
```

However what if I want to put a guard clause based on the Timex.Datetime type such as:

```
iex(5)> Timex.now  
#DateTime<2018-03-16 12:36:24.061549Z>
```

I cannot seem to be able to find a Timex.is_datetime function or equivalent.

Comment: Pattern match directly in the function clause instead: `def double(%DateTime{} = x) do`.

Comment: @mudasobwa aha. Does this work with built-in types as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DateTime`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.6.3/lib/elixir/lib/calendar/datetime.ex#L1) is a bare struct underneath. In Erlang (and hence in Elixir) one might pattern-match function arguments:

```rb
def double(%DateTime{} = x)
```

The above will match whenever `x` is a `DateTime` struct. For built-in types, like integers, there is no such a notation, hence guards are in use. For binaries, though, one might use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.<<>>/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1):

```rb
def double(<< x::binary >>)
```

which is roughly the same as:

```rb
def double(x) when is_binary(x)
```

Lists and maps might be pattern-matched as:

```rb
def double([]) do     # empty list
def double([h|t]) do  # non-empty list
def double(%{}) do    # any map (NB! not necessarily empty)
```

Also, one might pattern match *keys* in maps:

```rb
def double(%{foo: foo} = baz) do
  IO.inspect({foo, baz})
end
double(%{foo: 42, bar: 3.14})
#⇒ {42, %{foo: 42, bar: 3.14}}
```